lock a specific folder in 24.04
I've got a folder that needs locked because of the sensitivity of it's contents, private documents, copies of deeds and so on. I don't want to lock the whole Home folder, just this one folder. Veracrypt isn't the answer, because that works up to version 22.04 of Ubuntu.
My version is 24.04.
I've been roaming the internet, but a proper answer or solution isn't there to find! Can anyone help me please!

Have you seen this https://superuser.com/questions/1026431/how-to-password-protect-a-single-folder-on-ubuntu ?

if you just want to hide the folder rather than encrypt or password protect it, just place a period in front of the filename. That will hide it from casual observers.

Veracrypt works fine on 24.04, but it can't open Truecrypt volumes. Veracrypt's official website has provided a legacy version of Veracrypt that you can use to open a Truecrypt volume on Ubuntu 24.04 and then copy its contents to a new Veracrypt volume that is fully supported on Ubuntu 24.04 and later. Then uninstall the legacy Veracrypt version and install the version of Veracrypt that is specifically recommended for Ubuntu 24.04.

Try gpgtar:
GNU Privacy Guard, gpgtar encrypt or sign files into an archive
gpgtar [options] filename1 [ filename2, ... ] directory1 [ directory2, ... ]
gpgtar encrypts or signs files into an archive.  It is an gpg-ized tar using the same format as used by PGP's PGP Zip.
gpgtar understands these options:
   --create
   Put given files and directories into a vanilla ``ustar'' archive.

   --extract
   Extract all files from a vanilla ``ustar'' archive.

   --encrypt  -e
   Encrypt given files and directories into an archive.  This option may  be  combined  with  option --symmetric for an archive that may be decrypted via a secret key or a  passphrase.

    --decrypt -d
    Extract all files from an encrypted archive.

   --sign  -s
   Make a signed archive from the given files and directories.  This can be combined with option --encrypt to create a  signed  and then encrypted archive.

   --list-archive  -t
   List the contents of the specified archive.

   --symmetric  -c
   Encrypt  with  a  symmetric cipher using a passphrase.  The default symmetric cipher used is AES-128, but may be chosen with the              --cipher-algo option to gpg.

   --recipient user  -r user
   Encrypt for user id user. For details see gpg.

   --local-user user   -u user
   Use user as the key to sign with.  For details see gpg.

   --output file  -o file
   Write the archive to the specified file file.

   --verbose  -v     
   Enable extra informational output.

   --quiet  -q     
   Try to be as quiet as possible.

   --skip-crypto
   Skip all crypto operations and create or extract vanilla ``ustar'' archives.

   --dry-run
   Do not actually output the extracted files.

   --directory dir  -C dir 
   Extract the files into the directory dir.  The default is to take the directory name from the input filename.  If no input filename  is  known a directory named ‘GPGARCH’ is used.  For tarball creation, switch to directory dir before performing any operations.

   --files-from file  -T file
   Take the file names to work from the file file; one file per line.

   --null Modify option --files-from to use a binary nul instead of a linefeed to separate file names.

   --utf8-strings
   Assume that the file names read by --files-from are UTF-8 encoded.  This option has an effect only on Windows where  the  activecode page is otherwise assumed.

   --openpgp
   This option has no effect because OpenPGP encryption and signing is the default.

   --cms  
   This  option  is reserved and shall not be used.  It will eventually be used to encrypt or sign using the CMS protocol; but that is not yet implemented.

   --batch
   Use batch mode.  Never ask but use the default action.  This option is passed directly to gpg.

   --yes  
   Assume "yes" on most questions.  Often used together with --batch to overwrite existing files.  This option is  passed  directly to gpg.

   --no   
   Assume "no" on most questions.  This option is passed directly to gpg.

   --require-compliance
   This option is passed directly to gpg.

   --status-fd n
   Write special status strings to the file descriptor n.  See the file DETAILS in the documentation for a listing of them.

   --with-log
   When  extracting  an  encrypted tarball also write a log file with the gpg output to a file named after the extraction directory
          with the suffix ".log".

   --set-filename file
   Use the last component of file as the output directory.  The default is to take the directory name from the input filename.   If no input filename is known a directory named ‘GPGARCH’ is used.  This option is deprecated in favor of option --directory.

   --gpg gpgcmd
   Use the specified command gpgcmd instead of gpg.

   --gpg-args args
   Pass the specified extra options to gpg.

   --tar-args args
   Assume args are standard options of the command tar and parse them.  The only supported tar options are "--directory", "--files-from", and "--null" This is an obsolete options because those supported tar options can also be given directly.

   --version
   Print version of the program and exit.

   --help 
   Display a brief help page and exit.

   EXAMPLES
   

Encrypt the contents of directory ‘mydocs’ for user Bob to file ‘test1’:
     gpgtar --encrypt --output test1 -r Bob mydocs

   List the contents of archive ‘test1’:

     gpgtar --list-archive test1

Sources: Manual page gpgtar // run: man gpgtar
